# Cannot connect to exposed Docker port

Tags: java, docker, boot2docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I'm running Docker on OS X using the latest Docker Toolbox.

```
Docker version 1.10.2, build c3959b1
docker-machine version 0.6.0, build e27fb87
docker-compose version 1.6.0, build d99cad6
```

I have a Java app in a container built from the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM <my internal registry>/java:8

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-cp", "/var/app/scheduler/scheduler-jar-with-dependencies.jar", "com.myapp.scheduler.Application"]
```

and docker-compose.yml:

```
scheduler:
  image: <my internal registry>/scheduler
  command: -Dspring.profiles.active=local -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5050
  environment:
    TERM: xterm
  ports:
    - "4567:4567" # http port
    - "5050:5050" # java debug port
  volumes:
    - $SCHEDULER_GIT_ROOT/target:/var/app/scheduler
    - $LOG/scheduler:/var/log/scheduler
```

When I bring up the container, I can hit the http port from the browser using the VMs IP (192.168.99.100:4567).  I can't connect my debugger to the debug port, however, nor can I access that port at all through telnet, no matter what I change the port to.  `docker ps` yields:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                             COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
9395e0f20dd5        <my registry>/scheduler          "java -cp /var/app/sc"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes        0.0.0.0:4567->4567/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5050->5050/tcp   scheduler_scheduler_1
```

Anyone know why I can connect to the one port, but not the other?

EDIT: Here's the command from `docker inspect`:

```
"Path": "java",
"Args": [
    "-cp",
    "/var/app/scheduler/scheduler-jar-with-dependencies.jar",
    "com.mlbam.cms.scheduler.Application",
    "-Dspring.profiles.active=local",
    "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5050"
]
```

Comment: Can you post the `docker inspect` of the container? I'd suspect that the `command` needs to be in exec form just as the entrypoint is.

Comment: Because a process is listening to the one port you can connect, while no process uses the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wound up having nothing to do with Docker, but rather with the way I was running the java command.  The debug args have to come before the -cp:

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5050 -cp /var/app/scheduler/scheduler-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.myapp.scheduler.Application
```